# Relationship between ldconfig and ld.so.cache

Tags: linux, libraries, shared-library

After I restart my computer, `ld.so.cache` still has the information in it, so my questions are as follows:

1. Is the information always kept there? Isn't it being removed after restart or something like that? Like RAM or browser cache being deleted?
2. After I have removed an application that installed some shared libraries, does it know to also remove the information from the `ld.so.cache`? 
   If I use `ldconfig` will it remove the information? How does it actually work?
3. If I am installing a program, how does my computer know to use the new libraries that had been added? After `apt-get install` is `ldconfig` run?

Answer (score 15):

Linux programs are using libraries which are called shared objects. Shared objects have the extension .so. To see the S.O. usage of the command `ls` run `ldd /bin/ls`

1. By default, libs are stored in /lib /usr/lib and /usr/local/lib (/lib32, /lib64 for 32/64bit). The info where additional libs can be found are stored in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. In there are single .conf files which contain paths to specific libs i.e. `/opt/foo/lib`. Since the lookup in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ is very slow `ldconfig` generates the /etc/ld.so.cache file, which is a binary version of this which improves the lookup speed.
   To answer the first question. No, keep the file.
2. Yes, apt-get or dpkg (?) is triggering ldconfig. How it works - see 1.
3. Yes, see 1.

I hope, I got it right. Feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 8):

`apt-get` and `dpkg` both invoke `ldconfig` to rebuild the cache.

I imagine this is done at the end of every bulk operation but do not know for sure.

I don't think there is a way to remove specific data from the cache, it's just rebuilt e.g.:

```
rm /etc/ld.so.cache
ldconfig
```

You can use `ldconfig -p` to check the contents of the cache.

On my system `ldconfig` is invoked every reboot, but if `/etc/` is being used for the cache then it is not being created from scratch each time; you'd have to rebuild it yourself if you want that.

If you remove some libraries manually, you will have to rebuild it.