# ld.so.cache file is not a binary file

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking

I am currently studying for Comptia Linux+ exam and I am at the Shared Library chapter. Among all, it says that the **/etc/ld.so.cache** file is a binary file, but in my case it is not. It is a regular file, whose content I can easily view and fair enough it contains libraries locations.

```
ls -l /etc/ld.so.cache 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 154135 Feb 11 11:17 /etc/ld.so.cache
```

I've seen it in several materials that the cache file is a binary one and I am curious why this mismatch? Is that file's type distro-dependent?
I am using Fedora Workstation 27

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing up the definitions of a binary file, and an executable (binary) file.

The book is right mentioning `/etc/ld.so.cache` is a binary file (a data file).

As you can see running `file /etc/ld.so.cache`

```
$ file /etc/ld.so.cache 
/etc/ld.so.cache: data
```

From `man ld.so`:

> When resolving shared object dependencies, the dynamic linker first
>          inspects each dependency string to see if it contains a slash (this
>          can occur if a shared object pathname containing slashes was
>          specified at link time).  If a slash is found, then the dependency
>          string is interpreted as a (relative or absolute) pathname, and the
>          shared object is loaded using that pathname.
>
> If a shared object dependency does not contain a slash, then it is
>          searched for in the following order:
>
> .....
>
> - From the cache file /etc/ld.so.cache, which contains a compiled
>           list of candidate shared objects previously found in the augmented
>           library path.  If, however, the binary was linked with the -z
>           nodeflib linker option, shared objects in the default paths are
>           skipped.  Shared objects installed in hardware capability
>           directories (see below) are preferred to other shared objects.

From `man ldconfig`

> /etc/ld.so.cache
>
> File containing an ordered list of libraries found in the directories
>   specified in /etc/ld.so.conf, as well as those found in /lib and
>   /usr/lib.

Furthermore, `/etc/ld.so.cache` is regenerated upon running `ldconfig`. See [Relationship between ldconfig and ld.so.cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256893/relationship-between-ldconfig-and-ld-so-cache)

Double checking it is indeed a list of library files:

```
$ strings /etc/ld.so.cache | head -5
ld.so-1.7.0
glibc-ld.so.cache1.1
libz.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
libxtables.so.7
```

Or again, using `ldconfig -p`:

```
$ ldconfig -p | head -5
227 libs found in cache `/etc/ld.so.cache'
    libz.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
    libxtables.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libxtables.so.7
    libxml2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
    libxml-security-c.so.17 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml-security-c.so.17
```

Comment: I see. I did not know that. Its my first time at stack exchange and its nice to see that you are a very helpful community. Thanks for the info

Comment: @ErmirBajraktari Welcome to Unix&Linux Do not forget to accept the answer and keep using that user.

Answer (score 1):

It's a binary file because it contains binary data structures written to it using a program called `ldconfig`. The structure (Probably a Hashtable) is used to efficiently search and find the path of a shared object. The reason you see the pathes when you open the file in text mode is that because part of the structures contains strings or a table of strings (Path names) and that's all what the text editor can recognize as `ASCII` code strings (And therefore, show it on the screen).